# Python installation error (1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b)

Tags: python, windows-7, installation

I am trying to install Python but I'm running into following error:

```
An Error occurred during the installation of assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT, 
version="9.0.21022.8" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",
processorArchitecture="x86", type="win32"
```

I am using Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1, 32 bit OS with i7 Processor.
I have searched on the internet regarding this error but couldn't find any solution specific to my problem.

Comment: Could you include the full error message? What is that "error" that "occurred during the installation of assembly"?

Comment: Some ppl at https://bugs.python.org/issue26132 say that updates that are pending reboot to finish installation may cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It was some windows updates that had downloaded but not installed. I rebooted the PC waited for them to finish installing then tried again and all worked... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but I googled the error and it might not be related specifically to Python:
[Error while installing programs (Microsoft TechNet)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/5b3fd4ec-47d0-4a9a-9729-27793dc4247f)

To quote the moderator that posted the solution:

> The cause could be an unsuccessful install of prior Windows Updates
>   OR Custom MSI packages could have left over faulty registry keys under
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMPONETS.